# Add remote box to Vagrant with a custom name

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I wish to completely automate the deployment of my virtual machines so I want to add some boxes from a cloud storage.

Can I set up *Vagrantfile* to make '*vagrant up*' download and add my boxes before deployment?

**If not**, I wish to use

```
vagrant box add https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64
```

to download one of my boxes, but how do I set a custom name for it?

Works:

```
vagrant box add my-box-with-a-custom-name precise64.box
```

Does not work:

```
vagrant box add my-box-with-a-custom-name https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a more convenient solution.

In Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.box = "my-box"
config.vm.box_url = "http://my-box_download_link
```

If there is no my-box it downloads and adds it automatically.

Comment: indeed, forgot about this parameter!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I set up Vagrantfile to make 'vagrant up' download and add my
>   boxes before deployment?

yes you can - If you just create a Vagrantfile and set the property

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
```

vagrant will search for the box and if it does not find, it will download. The box will be added with the default ubuntu/trusty64

If really you want to give the name of your choice you can
1. wget the box file 
2. vagrant box add my-box-with-a-custom-name /path/to/box/file
3. vagrant init my-box-with-a-custom-name